# Symfony2 - Checking if a file exists in Twig

Tags: image, symfony, twig

Is there a way to check if the file exists in Twig for an image uploaded in a newly created post?

The way I have my post setup is if an image is not uploaded the Twig template will show an empty box with the proportions of where the image should be, but it's a blank box that's awkward to look at.

Question, is if there is a specific command to use with an if statement to check if a file exists if so, display the image code if not do not display the image code.

**Image code: (this is the code I want to hide if no image exists to get rid of the empty box)**

```
<div class="entry-thumbnail">
    <img width="230" height="172" src="{{ asset(['images/', post.image]|join) }}" class="" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could write a twig extension and use some code like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;


    $this->fs=new Filesystem();

    if (!$this->fs->exists($directory)) {
        $this->logger->info("there is no ".$directory." ...");
    } else {
        $this->logger->info("Directory ".$directory."  already exists.");
    }
```

but i would rather use javascripz like

in your img tag :

```
<img ... onError="this.src='imagefound.gif';" />
```

update:

The image Tag has an onError-Handler that triggers when the image in the src attribute is not found. So instead of using this simple inline syntax you could do the same like :

pseudo jquery code:

```
$(document).on('error','img',function(){
    $(this).attr("src","../path/to/placeholerImage.png");
});
```

Comment: you mean like i just did ?